# Using mysqli on php with built in webserver

Tags: php, windows, mysqli

I am using php -S for a quick server to test my code. I want to use mysqli to access my database, but I am having trouble enabling it in Windows.

I could not find the php.ini file even though it is listed as being in C:
\WINDOWS. I created my own and put the contents of php.ini-development in it. I uncommented the extension for mysqli and updated the extension_dir. I am using php 7.3 and MySQL 8.

```
<?php
$dbConn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1:3306','root','','users') or die("Failed to connect to DB");
?>
```

The error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in
>   C:\Users\gfr\Desktop\test.php:2 Stack trace:
>   **#0 {main}**   thrown in C:\Users\gfr\Desktop\test.php on line 2

As requested here is the output of php -I

> phpinfo() PHP Version => 7.3.1
>
> System => Windows NT DESKTOP-17OE0MP 10.0 build 17134 (Windows 10)
>   AMD64 Build Date => Jan  9 2019 22:16:33 Compiler => MSVC15 (Visual
>   C++ 2017) Architecture => x64 Configure Command => cscript /nologo
>   configure.js  "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack"
>   "--disable-zts"
>   "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared"
>   "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared"
>   "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared"
>   "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo" Server API => Command Line Interface
>   Virtual Directory Support => disabled Configuration File (php.ini)
>   Path => C:\WINDOWS Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64\php.ini Scan this dir for
>   additional .ini files => (none) Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
>   PHP API => 20180731 PHP Extension => 20180731 Zend Extension =>
>   320180731 Zend Extension Build => API320180731,NTS,VC15 PHP Extension
>   Build => API20180731,NTS,VC15 Debug Build => no Thread Safety =>
>   disabled Zend Signal Handling => disabled Zend Memory Manager =>
>   enabled Zend Multibyte Support => disabled IPv6 Support => enabled
>   DTrace Support => disabled
>
> Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip,
>   compress.zlib, phar Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp
>   Registered Stream Filters => convert.iconv.*, string.rot13,
>   string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*,
>   consumed, dechunk, zlib.*
>
> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v3.3.1, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>
> ---
>
> Configuration
>
> bcmath
>
> BCMath support => enabled
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value bcmath.scale => 0 => 0
>
> calendar
>
> Calendar support => enabled
>
> Core
>
> PHP Version => 7.3.1
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value allow_url_fopen => On => On
>   allow_url_include => Off => Off arg_separator.input => & => &
>   arg_separator.output => & => & auto_append_file => no value => no
>   value auto_globals_jit => On => On auto_prepend_file => no value => no
>   value browscap => no value => no value default_charset => UTF-8 =>
>   UTF-8 default_mimetype => text/html => text/html disable_classes => no
>   value => no value disable_functions => no value => no value
>   display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT display_startup_errors => Off =>
>   Off doc_root => no value => no value docref_ext => no value => no
>   value docref_root => no value => no value enable_dl => On => On
>   enable_post_data_reading => On => On error_append_string => no value
>   => no value error_log => no value => no value error_prepend_string => no value => no value error_reporting => no value => no value
>   expose_php => On => On extension_dir => C:\php\ext => C:\php\ext
>   file_uploads => On => On hard_timeout => 2 => 2 highlight.comment =>
>   #FF8000 =>
>
> ## FF8000">#FF8000 highlight.default => #0000BB => #0000BB highlight.html => #000000 =>
>
> style="color: #000000">#000000 highlight.keyword => #007700 => 
>   
>   007700">#007700 highlight.string => #DD0000 => #DD0000 html_errors => Off => Off ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
>
> ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
>   implicit_flush => On => On include_path => .;C:\php\pear =>
>   .;C:\php\pear input_encoding => no value => no value internal_encoding
>   => no value => no value log_errors => Off => Off log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024 mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
>   mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value mail.log => no
>   value => no value max_execution_time => 0 => 0 max_file_uploads => 20
>   => 20 max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64 max_input_time => -1 => -1 max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000 memory_limit => 128M => 128M
>   open_basedir => no value => no value output_buffering => 0 => 0
>   output_encoding => no value => no value output_handler => no value =>
>   no value post_max_size => 8M => 8M precision => 14 => 14
>   realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
>   register_argc_argv => On => On report_memleaks => On => On
>   report_zend_debug => Off => Off request_order => no value => no value
>   sendmail_from => no value => no value sendmail_path => no value => no
>   value serialize_precision => -1 => -1 short_open_tag => On => On SMTP
>   => localhost => localhost smtp_port => 25 => 25 sys_temp_dir => no value => no value syslog.facility => LOG_USER => LOG_USER
>   syslog.filter => no-ctrl => no-ctrl syslog.ident => php => php
>   track_errors => Off => Off unserialize_callback_func => no value => no
>   value upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M upload_tmp_dir => no value => no
>   value user_dir => no value => no value user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 =>
>   300 user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini variables_order =>
>   EGPCS => EGPCS windows.show_crt_warning => Off => Off
>   xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0 xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
>   zend.assertions => 1 => 1 zend.detect_unicode => On => On
>   zend.enable_gc => On => On zend.multibyte => Off => Off
>   zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
>
> ctype
>
> ctype functions => enabled
>
> date
>
> date/time support => enabled timelib version => 2018.01RC2 "Olson"
>   Timezone Database Version => 2018.5 Timezone Database => internal
>   Default timezone => UTC
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value date.default_latitude =>
>   31.7667 => 31.7667 date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333 date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333 date.sunset_zenith =>
>   90.583333 => 90.583333 date.timezone => no value => no value
>
> dom
>
> DOM/XML => enabled DOM/XML API Version => 20031129 libxml Version =>
>   2.9.8 HTML Support => enabled XPath Support => enabled XPointer Support => enabled Schema Support => enabled RelaxNG Support =>
>   enabled
>
> filter
>
> Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value filter.default => unsafe_raw
>   => unsafe_raw filter.default_flags => no value => no value
>
> hash
>
> hash support => enabled Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224
>   sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384
>   sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3
>   tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru
>   snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164
>   fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3
>   haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5
>   haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5
>
> MHASH support => Enabled MHASH API Version => Emulated Support
>
> iconv
>
> iconv support => enabled iconv implementation => "libiconv" iconv
>   library version => 1.15
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value iconv.input_encoding => no
>   value => no value iconv.internal_encoding => no value => no value
>   iconv.output_encoding => no value => no value
>
> json
>
> json support => enabled json version => 1.7.0
>
> libxml
>
> libXML support => active libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.8 libXML
>   Loaded Version => 20908 libXML streams => enabled
>
> mysqlnd
>
> mysqlnd => enabled Version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id:
>   401a40ebd5e281cf22215acdc170723a1519aaa9 $ Compression => supported
>   core SSL => supported extended SSL => not supported Command buffer
>   size => 4096 Read buffer size => 32768 Read timeout => 86400
>   Collecting statistics => Yes Collecting memory statistics => No
>   Tracing => n/a Loaded plugins =>
>   mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
>   API Extensions =>
>
> mysqlnd statistics => bytes_sent => 0 bytes_received => 0 packets_sent
>   => 0 packets_received => 0 protocol_overhead_in => 0 protocol_overhead_out => 0 bytes_received_ok_packet => 0
>   bytes_received_eof_packet => 0 bytes_received_rset_header_packet => 0
>   bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet => 0
>   bytes_received_rset_row_packet => 0
>   bytes_received_prepare_response_packet => 0
>   bytes_received_change_user_packet => 0 packets_sent_command => 0
>   packets_received_ok => 0 packets_received_eof => 0
>   packets_received_rset_header => 0 packets_received_rset_field_meta =>
>   0 packets_received_rset_row => 0 packets_received_prepare_response =>
>   0 packets_received_change_user => 0 result_set_queries => 0
>   non_result_set_queries => 0 no_index_used => 0 bad_index_used => 0
>   slow_queries => 0 buffered_sets => 0 unbuffered_sets => 0
>   ps_buffered_sets => 0 ps_unbuffered_sets => 0 flushed_normal_sets => 0
>   flushed_ps_sets => 0 ps_prepared_never_executed => 0
>   ps_prepared_once_executed => 0 rows_fetched_from_server_normal => 0
>   rows_fetched_from_server_ps => 0 rows_buffered_from_client_normal => 0
>   rows_buffered_from_client_ps => 0
>   rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered => 0
>   rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered => 0
>   rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered => 0
>   rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered => 0
>   rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor => 0 rows_affected_normal => 0
>   rows_affected_ps => 0 rows_skipped_normal => 0 rows_skipped_ps => 0
>   copy_on_write_saved => 0 copy_on_write_performed => 0
>   command_buffer_too_small => 0 connect_success => 0 connect_failure =>
>   0 connection_reused => 0 reconnect => 0 pconnect_success => 0
>   active_connections => 0 active_persistent_connections => 0
>   explicit_close => 0 implicit_close => 0 disconnect_close => 0
>   in_middle_of_command_close => 0 explicit_free_result => 0
>   implicit_free_result => 0 explicit_stmt_close => 0 implicit_stmt_close
>   => 0 mem_emalloc_count => 0 mem_emalloc_amount => 0 mem_ecalloc_count => 0 mem_ecalloc_amount => 0 mem_erealloc_count => 0 mem_erealloc_amount => 0 mem_efree_count => 0 mem_efree_amount => 0
>   mem_malloc_count => 0 mem_malloc_amount => 0 mem_calloc_count => 0
>   mem_calloc_amount => 0 mem_realloc_count => 0 mem_realloc_amount => 0
>   mem_free_count => 0 mem_free_amount => 0 mem_estrndup_count => 0
>   mem_strndup_count => 0 mem_estrdup_count => 0 mem_strdup_count => 0
>   mem_edupl_count => 0 mem_dupl_count => 0 proto_text_fetched_null => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_bit => 0 proto_text_fetched_tinyint => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_short => 0 proto_text_fetched_int24 => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_int => 0 proto_text_fetched_bigint => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_decimal => 0 proto_text_fetched_float => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_double => 0 proto_text_fetched_date => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_year => 0 proto_text_fetched_time => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_datetime => 0 proto_text_fetched_timestamp => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_string => 0 proto_text_fetched_blob => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_enum => 0 proto_text_fetched_set => 0
>   proto_text_fetched_geometry => 0 proto_text_fetched_other => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_null => 0 proto_binary_fetched_bit => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_tinyint => 0 proto_binary_fetched_short => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_int24 => 0 proto_binary_fetched_int => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_bigint => 0 proto_binary_fetched_decimal => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_float => 0 proto_binary_fetched_double => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_date => 0 proto_binary_fetched_year => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_time => 0 proto_binary_fetched_datetime => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_timestamp => 0 proto_binary_fetched_string => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_json => 0 proto_binary_fetched_blob => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_enum => 0 proto_binary_fetched_set => 0
>   proto_binary_fetched_geometry => 0 proto_binary_fetched_other => 0
>   init_command_executed_count => 0 init_command_failed_count => 0
>   com_quit => 0 com_init_db => 0 com_query => 0 com_field_list => 0
>   com_create_db => 0 com_drop_db => 0 com_refresh => 0 com_shutdown => 0
>   com_statistics => 0 com_process_info => 0 com_connect => 0
>   com_process_kill => 0 com_debug => 0 com_ping => 0 com_time => 0
>   com_delayed_insert => 0 com_change_user => 0 com_binlog_dump => 0
>   com_table_dump => 0 com_connect_out => 0 com_register_slave => 0
>   com_stmt_prepare => 0 com_stmt_execute => 0 com_stmt_send_long_data =>
>   0 com_stmt_close => 0 com_stmt_reset => 0 com_stmt_set_option => 0
>   com_stmt_fetch => 0 com_deamon => 0 bytes_received_real_data_normal =>
>   0 bytes_received_real_data_ps => 0
>
> pcre
>
> PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled PCRE
>   Library Version => 10.32 2018-09-10 PCRE Unicode Version => 11.0.0
>   PCRE JIT Support => enabled PCRE JIT Target => x86 64bit (little
>   endian + unaligned)
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value pcre.backtrack_limit =>
>   1000000 => 1000000 pcre.jit => 1 => 1 pcre.recursion_limit => 100000
>   => 100000
>
> PDO
>
> PDO support => enabled PDO drivers =>
>
> Phar
>
> Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled Phar API version => 1.1.1
>   Phar-based phar archives => enabled Tar-based phar archives => enabled
>   ZIP-based phar archives => enabled gzip compression => enabled bzip2
>   compression => disabled (install ext/bz2) OpenSSL support => disabled
>   (install ext/openssl)
>
> Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik. Phar
>   fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger. Portions of tar
>   implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle. Directive =>
>   Local Value => Master Value phar.cache_list => no value => no value
>   phar.readonly => On => On phar.require_hash => On => On
>
> readline
>
> Readline Support => enabled Readline library => WinEditLine
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value cli.pager => no value => no
>   value cli.prompt => \b >  => \b >
>
> Reflection
>
> Reflection => enabled
>
> session
>
> Session Support => enabled Registered save handlers => files user
>   Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary wddx
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value session.auto_start => Off =>
>   Off session.cache_expire => 180 => 180 session.cache_limiter =>
>   nocache => nocache session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
>   session.cookie_httponly => 0 => 0 session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
>   session.cookie_path => / => / session.cookie_samesite => no value =>
>   no value session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0 session.gc_divisor => 100 =>
>   100 session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440 session.gc_probability => 1
>   => 1 session.lazy_write => On => On session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID session.referer_check => no value => no value
>   session.save_handler => files => files session.save_path => no value
>   => no value session.serialize_handler => php => php session.sid_bits_per_character => 4 => 4 session.sid_length => 32 =>
>   32 session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
>   session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
>   session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
>   session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
>   session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS =>
>   PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS session.upload_progress.prefix =>
>   upload_progress_ => upload_progress_ session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
>   session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1 session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
>   session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0
>
> SimpleXML
>
> SimpleXML support => enabled Schema support => enabled
>
> SPL
>
> SPL support => enabled Interfaces => OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator,
>   SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject Classes => AppendIterator,
>   ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException,
>   BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator,
>   DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator,
>   FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator,
>   InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException,
>   LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator,
>   OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException,
>   ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator,
>   RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator,
>   RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator,
>   RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator,
>   RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException,
>   SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray,
>   SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue,
>   SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException,
>   UnexpectedValueException
>
> standard
>
> Dynamic Library Support => enabled Internal Sendmail Support for
>   Windows => enabled
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value assert.active => 1 => 1
>   assert.bail => 0 => 0 assert.callback => no value => no value
>   assert.exception => 0 => 0 assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0 assert.warning
>   => 1 => 1 auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0 default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60 from => no value => no value session.trans_sid_hosts => no
>   value => no value session.trans_sid_tags =>
>   a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
>   url_rewriter.hosts => no value => no value url_rewriter.tags => form=
>   => form= user_agent => no value => no value
>
> tokenizer
>
> Tokenizer Support => enabled
>
> wddx
>
> WDDX Support => enabled WDDX Session Serializer => enabled
>
> xml
>
> XML Support => active XML Namespace Support => active libxml2 Version
>   => 2.9.8
>
> xmlreader
>
> XMLReader => enabled
>
> xmlwriter
>
> XMLWriter => enabled
>
> zip
>
> Zip => enabled Zip version => 1.15.4 Libzip version => 1.4.0
>
> zlib
>
> ZLib Support => enabled Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib:// Stream
>   Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate Compiled Version => 1.2.11 Linked
>   Version => 1.2.11
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value zlib.output_compression =>
>   Off => Off zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
>   zlib.output_handler => no value => no value
>
> Additional Modules
>
> Module Name
>
> Environment
>
> Variable => Value ALLUSERSPROFILE => C:\ProgramData APPDATA =>
>   C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Roaming CommonProgramFiles => C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files CommonProgramFiles(x86) => C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files CommonProgramW6432 => C:\Program Files\Common Files
>   COMPUTERNAME => DESKTOP-17OE0MP ComSpec => C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
>   configsetroot => C:\WINDOWS\ConfigSetRoot DriverData =>
>   C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData HOMEDRIVE => C: HOMEPATH =>
>   \Users\gfr LOCALAPPDATA => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local LOGONSERVER =>
>   \DESKTOP-17OE0MP NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS => 4 OneDrive =>
>   C:\Users\gfr\OneDrive OS => Windows_NT Path => C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program
>   Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
>   Files\platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows\platform-tools\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA
>   NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64;C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64 PATHEXT =>
>   .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE => AMD64 PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER => Intel64 Family
>   6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel PROCESSOR_LEVEL => 6
>   PROCESSOR_REVISION => 3d04 ProgramData => C:\ProgramData ProgramFiles
>   => C:\Program Files ProgramFiles(x86) => C:\Program Files (x86) ProgramW6432 => C:\Program Files PROMPT => $P$G PSModulePath =>
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
>   PUBLIC => C:\Users\Public SESSIONNAME => Console SystemDrive => C:
>   SystemRoot => C:\WINDOWS TEMP => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Temp TMP
>   => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Temp USERDOMAIN => DESKTOP-17OE0MP USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE => DESKTOP-17OE0MP USERNAME => gfr
>   USERPROFILE => C:\Users\gfr VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH => C:\Program
>   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ windir => C:\WINDOWS
>
> PHP Variables
>
> Variable => Value $_SERVER['ALLUSERSPROFILE'] => C:\ProgramData
>   $_SERVER['APPDATA'] => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Roaming
>   $_SERVER['CommonProgramFiles'] => C:\Program Files\Common Files
>   $_SERVER['CommonProgramFiles(x86)'] => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files $_SERVER['CommonProgramW6432'] => C:\Program Files\Common Files
>   $_SERVER['COMPUTERNAME'] => DESKTOP-17OE0MP $_SERVER['ComSpec'] =>
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe $_SERVER['configsetroot'] =>
>   C:\WINDOWS\ConfigSetRoot $_SERVER['DriverData'] =>
>   C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData $_SERVER['HOMEDRIVE'] => C:
>   $_SERVER['HOMEPATH'] => \Users\gfr $_SERVER['LOCALAPPDATA'] =>
>   C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local $_SERVER['LOGONSERVER'] =>
>   \DESKTOP-17OE0MP $_SERVER['NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'] => 4
>   $_SERVER['OneDrive'] => C:\Users\gfr\OneDrive $_SERVER['OS'] =>
>   Windows_NT $_SERVER['Path'] => C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program
>   Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
>   Files\platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows\platform-tools\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA
>   NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64;C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64 $_SERVER['PATHEXT'] =>
>   .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
>   $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE'] => AMD64
>   $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER'] => Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping
>   4, GenuineIntel $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_LEVEL'] => 6
>   $_SERVER['PROCESSOR_REVISION'] => 3d04 $_SERVER['ProgramData'] =>
>   C:\ProgramData $_SERVER['ProgramFiles'] => C:\Program Files
>   $_SERVER['ProgramFiles(x86)'] => C:\Program Files (x86)
>   $_SERVER['ProgramW6432'] => C:\Program Files $_SERVER['PROMPT'] =>
>   $P$G $_SERVER['PSModulePath'] =>
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
>   $_SERVER['PUBLIC'] => C:\Users\Public $_SERVER['SESSIONNAME'] =>
>   Console $_SERVER['SystemDrive'] => C: $_SERVER['SystemRoot'] =>
>   C:\WINDOWS $_SERVER['TEMP'] => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Temp
>   $_SERVER['TMP'] => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Temp
>   $_SERVER['USERDOMAIN'] => DESKTOP-17OE0MP
>   $_SERVER['USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE'] => DESKTOP-17OE0MP
>   $_SERVER['USERNAME'] => gfr $_SERVER['USERPROFILE'] => C:\Users\gfr
>   $_SERVER['VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH'] => C:\Program
>   Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ $_SERVER['windir'] => C:\WINDOWS
>   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] =>
>   $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] => $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] =>
>   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] => $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] =>
>   1547758947.2805 $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] => 1547758947 $_SERVER['argv'] => Array ( )
>
> $_SERVER['argc'] => 0 $_ENV['ALLUSERSPROFILE'] => C:\ProgramData
>   $_ENV['APPDATA'] => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Roaming
>   $_ENV['CommonProgramFiles'] => C:\Program Files\Common Files
>   $_ENV['CommonProgramFiles(x86)'] => C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files $_ENV['CommonProgramW6432'] => C:\Program Files\Common Files
>   $_ENV['COMPUTERNAME'] => DESKTOP-17OE0MP $_ENV['ComSpec'] =>
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe $_ENV['configsetroot'] =>
>   C:\WINDOWS\ConfigSetRoot $_ENV['DriverData'] =>
>   C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData $_ENV['HOMEDRIVE'] => C:
>   $_ENV['HOMEPATH'] => \Users\gfr $_ENV['LOCALAPPDATA'] =>
>   C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local $_ENV['LOGONSERVER'] => \DESKTOP-17OE0MP
>   $_ENV['NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'] => 4 $_ENV['OneDrive'] =>
>   C:\Users\gfr\OneDrive $_ENV['OS'] => Windows_NT $_ENV['Path'] =>
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program
>   Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program
>   Files\platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows\platform-tools\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA
>   NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64;C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64 $_ENV['PATHEXT'] =>
>   .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
>   $_ENV['PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE'] => AMD64 $_ENV['PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER']
>   => Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel $_ENV['PROCESSOR_LEVEL'] => 6 $_ENV['PROCESSOR_REVISION'] => 3d04
>   $_ENV['ProgramData'] => C:\ProgramData $_ENV['ProgramFiles'] =>
>   C:\Program Files $_ENV['ProgramFiles(x86)'] => C:\Program Files (x86)
>   $_ENV['ProgramW6432'] => C:\Program Files $_ENV['PROMPT'] => $P$G
>   $_ENV['PSModulePath'] =>
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
>   $_ENV['PUBLIC'] => C:\Users\Public $_ENV['SESSIONNAME'] => Console
>   $_ENV['SystemDrive'] => C: $_ENV['SystemRoot'] => C:\WINDOWS
>   $_ENV['TEMP'] => C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Temp $_ENV['TMP'] =>
>   C:\Users\gfr\AppData\Local\Temp $_ENV['USERDOMAIN'] => DESKTOP-17OE0MP
>   $_ENV['USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE'] => DESKTOP-17OE0MP
>   $_ENV['USERNAME'] => gfr $_ENV['USERPROFILE'] => C:\Users\gfr
>   $_ENV['VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH'] => C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
>   $_ENV['windir'] => C:\WINDOWS
>
> PHP License This program is free software; you can redistribute it
>   and/or modify it under the terms of the PHP License as published by
>   the PHP Group and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE
>
> This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
>   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
>   questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.

Comment: Is mysqli listed in `php -m`? Are you using xampp? `"even though it is listed as being in C: \WINDOWS"` How did you get the list?

Comment: With the -S parm to PHP did you also pass the path to the ini file you created?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full output of `php -i`

Comment: I am not using xampp, just php built in webserver. I got the list from phpinfo(). I tried to do php -S <path to php.ini> and got invalid address.

Comment: The ini file you need to be modifying is `C:\Program Files (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64\php.ini` as shown in the output of `php -i`.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\php-7.3.1-nts-Win32-VC15-x64\php.ini is the one I created and modified to enable mysqli, but I still get the error. Do I have to do something else besides uncomment lines in php.ini?